# Child commit marked as "Not Current" in Gerrit relation chain

Tags: git, gerrit

I was trying to split a Gerrit relation chain into independent commits because their changes are in separate sections of the project.

```
main -- A -- B

main -- A
    \__ B
```

I didn't know what commands to use, so I tried pushing Commit B with the same Change ID in a fresh git repo on tip of main (i.e. `git reset --hard origin/main`). On Commit B's review, the relation chain doesn't have Commit A (expected), however Commit A's review still shows Commit B in its chain and with "Not Current", so it probably wasn't the correct way to do it.

How can I fix this so Commit A's relation chain doesn't show Commit B?

Answer (score 1):

You did it right, and there is indeed still a relationship between changes A and B!

When you send the commit of B rebased on `origin/main` and send it back to Gerrit it checks the received commit for a prexisting change having the same `(project, branch, Change-Id)`. If it does, Gerrit attaches your new commit as a new patchset to the same change.

Looking again at your example but this time appending the patchset numbers to your changes `A` and `B`, you have started with:

```
main -- A,1 -- B,1
```

When looking at **either** `A` or `B` in the Web UI you can see the relation chain:

```
B
A
```

Then locally you rebase B onto `main` and your local repository has:

```
main -- A -- B
    \-- B (rebased)
```

When sending that `B (rebased)` Gerrit attaches it to the change `B` as a second patchset. On the Gerrit side the repository looks like:

```
main -- A,1 -- B,1
     \-- B,2
```

When looking at A the Web UI shows:

```
B (not current)
A
```

That is because `A` still has a followup change which is patchset B,1.

When heading to `B,2` you would no more see a relationship with `A` since you rebased it.

Once `B,2` is merged, Gerrit detects it and when looking at `A` I think it would show:

```
B (merged)
A
```

You can amend `A` and send it back for review. That will create a new patchset which is not attached to `B`. On the Gerrit side the repository will look like:

```
main -- A,1 -- B,1  (original chain, now obsolete)
    \-- B,2
    \-- A,2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to cherry-pick the changes, the easiest way is to use the download commands. This will result in something like this:

Here I assume A = change 9642 and B = 9643

```
git reset --hard origin/main
# fetch change A
git fetch ssh://USER@example.com:29418/project refs/changes/42/9642/1 && git cherry-pick FETCH_HEAD
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/main

git reset --hard origin/main
# Fetch change B
git fetch ssh://USER@example.com:29418/project refs/changes/42/9643/1 && git cherry-pick FETCH_HEAD
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/main
```